# How to emit() LiveData results to an existing LiveData object?

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

The coroutine `LiveData` example in the [official Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) gives the following example using `emit()`:

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
    val data = database.loadUser() // loadUser is a suspend function.
    emit(data)
}
```

Every example of `emit()` I have seen including this [ProAndroidDev tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/coroutines-with-architecture-components-4c223a51b112) creates a new `LiveData` object when using `emit()`. How can I get a `LiveDataScope` from a `LiveData` object that has already been created and `emit()` values to it? E.g.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val user: MutableLiveData<User> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getUser(): LiveData<User> {
        return user
    }

    fun loadUser() {
        // Code to emit() values to existing user LiveData object.
    }
```

Thanks so much and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: there is no need. just observe the `user` in the fragment and you are done. that's live data with coroutines.

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher How would I handle the case where I want to send another network request to refresh the `LiveData` object? Or the case where I want to wait for a button click before I update the `LiveData` object? Using the example I provided only allows updating the `LiveData` object once, when the `Fragment` first instantiates the `ViewModel`. I'm sure I'm missing something, thanks for the help!

Comment: the https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations.html should be a solution I guess.

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher How can I still use `emit()` if I'm using one of the `Transformations`?

Comment: use Flow instead of LiveData?

Comment: Are you looking for a `MediatorLiveData`?

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
fun loadUser() {
     user.value = User()
}
```

Listen to it via

```
 myViewModel.getUser().observe(this, EventObserver { user ->
     // do something with user
 })
```

Hope it helps